# Implementing one to one relation ship spring hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, relational-database

I have a table `cards` which is related to some other master tables (divisions and units) with one to one relation.

On UI I am showing drop downs to select the division and unit values for card, this is the function to create form in `CardController.java`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addCardForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addCardForm(ModelMap map)
    {
        map.addAttribute("divisions", divisionService.getAllDivisions());
        map.addAttribute("units", unitService.getAllUnits());
        return "admin/addCard";
    }
```

`addCard.jsp` :

```
<form:form  method="post" action="addCard">
<table cellspacing="10" id="card-table">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="division" class="control-label">Division : </label></td>
                <td><select name="division" class="selectpicker">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <c:forEach items="${divisions}" var="division">
                        <option value="${division.id}">${division.name}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="unit" class="control-label">Unit : </label></td>
                <td><select name="unit" class="selectpicker">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <c:forEach items="${units}" var="unit">
                        <option value="${unit.id}">${unit.name}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Drop downs are populated with the data but on submitting form its not setting division or unit to the cardEntity object they are set to null, this is the addCard function in controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addCard", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCard(@ModelAttribute(value="card") CardEntity card, BindingResult result)
    {
        cardService.addCard(card);
        //card.getDivision();  -- this is null
        return "redirect:/card";
    }
```

There are other fields which are added in the card except drop downs.

```
CardEntity.java


@Entity
@Table(name="cards")
@Proxy(lazy=false)
public class CardEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="division_id", referencedColumnName="id")  
    private DivisionEntity division;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="unit_of_qty_id", referencedColumnName="id")  
    private UnitEntity units;

    public DivisionEntity getDivision() {
        return division;
    }

    public void setDivision(DivisionEntity division) {
        this.division = division;
    }

    public UnitEntity getUnits() {
        return units;
    }

    public void setUnits(UnitEntity units) {
        this.units = units;
    }

}
```

Edit :

I have to set divisionEntity and unitEntity manually :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addCard", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCard(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute(value="card") CardEntity card, BindingResult result)
    {
        card.setDivision(divisionService.findOne(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("division"))));
        card.setUnit(unitService.findOne(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("unit"))));
        cardService.addCard(card);
        return "redirect:/card";
    }
```

So I guess the  problem is `divisionEntity` and `unitEntity` objects are not set in card after submitting the form.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: if i select a division or unit from drop down and submit the form it should save the division_id and unit_of_qty_id in card table but they are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this too:

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="division.id" class="control-label">Division : </label></td>
    <td><select name="division.id" class="selectpicker">
        <option>Select</option>
        <c:forEach items="${divisions}" var="division">
            <option value="${division.id}">${division.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
        </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="unit.id" class="control-label">Unit : </label></td>
    <td><select name="unit.id" class="selectpicker">
        <option>Select</option>
        <c:forEach items="${units}" var="unit">
            <option value="${unit.id}">${unit.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
        </select></td>
</tr>
```

The rest is same as your original. But:

1. Make sure you have a default constrcutor in `Division` class;
2. The `CardEntity` should have `getUnit()` and `setUnit()`, not `getUnits()` and `setUnits()`.

Hope it help.

Comment: it was my typo for `setUnits()` and `getUnits()`, changing from `<select name="division" class="selectpicker">` to `<select name="division.id" class="selectpicker">` has worked. Thanks!